# Resonant/Great Resonant Soul bug

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm farming awe stones using a method involving offline play, and re spawning offline phantoms. The one in particular that I am farming Rhoy the Explorer.

However, after a few rounds of him re spawning, my spells (Res. Soul and Great Res. Soul) are only dealing around 40-60 damage per hit. Originally I was pulling off ~400 damage per hit. What happened?

I am currently using the Idol's Chime +1, and have 31 FAI/INT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a bug, I completely forgot that Hexes require souls to fuel the spells. Originally I had upwards of 20,000 souls, but I lost them so now I am casting with no fuel. Hence the incredible difference in damage output